# How to avoid overlapping logs with ThreadPoolExecutor?

Tags: python, multithreading

I would like to log some information by thread. But the multi-threading code I wrote is leading to overlapping logs and this makes the logs not readable and easy-to-use.

```py
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor
from io import StringIO
import logging

from pipelines import Pipeline # Class with run method doing some log info / warning
from preprocessing import Preprocess # Same

if __name__ == "__main__":

    log_stream = StringIO()
    logging.basicConfig(stream=log_stream, level=logging.INFO)
    logger = logging.getLogger("main")

    logger.info("Starting application")
    
    # code to get all csv files in a path and store them in a `files` variable
    
    def data_generator(files=files)
        for file in files:
            logger.info("Generate preprocessed data for file %s", file)
            dataframe = Preprocess.load(file)
            preprocessed_dataframe = Preprocess.run(dataframe)
            yield preprocessed_dataframe
    
    data = data_generator()    
    
    logger.info("Run pipeline on the available data")
    with ThreadPoolExecutor(3) as pool:
        results = pool.map(Pipeline.run, data)
    logger.info("Got following results %s", results)
```

Some specific infos about `Preprocess`. The class is quite simple. The method `load` reads a csv using pandas. The method `run` fills some missing values.

Do you know a way I can use to output the logs by keeping the natural order that we can find by running the code without threading :

```py
    logger.info("Run pipeline on the available data")
    results = [Pipeline.run(dataframe) for dataframe in data]
    logger.info("Got following results %s", results)
```

Which would output something close to that :

```
INFO : Starting application
INFO : Run pipeline on the available data
INFO : Generate preprocessed data for file data/toto.csv
INFO : Loading this file
INFO : Handle missing values
INFO : Running pipeline on preprocessed data
INFO : Success
INFO : Generate preprocessed data for file data/tata.csv
INFO : Loading this file
INFO : Handle missing values
INFO : Running pipeline on preprocessed data
INFO : Success
...
...
INFO : Got following results [150, 200, ...]
```

I want to keep the logs readable. Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: From the provided code: Currently you should get something like `loading` related logs in sequence and then a bunch of "unordered" processing logs and then the result. Right? You want now sequentially logged data? In multi-thredding (and processing) this is hard to do, as you WANT the tasks to be run individually and not in sequence (otherwise no speed gain). So you'd need to store the log messages somewhere else and add then post-factum to the log. But this is no longer "live logging" and could hide bugs, etc.

Comment: That was a thing I tried to do, and it works for this little example. But in a more complex project, I may have to do a lot of modifications to store the logs in the modules `pipelines` and `preprocessing`. In such a project, I would have a lot of modules that act like `Pipeline` and would call them depending on a parameter given by the CLI. So, it might be tricky to store logs and then print them....

Comment: Is it possible to process the logs after they got written in a file ? The process would re-ordering the logs. In my example, I could use the variable `file` to identify the logs individually.

Comment: Yes, this approach would not work for complex setups. You can print the name of the logger (e.g. with `'format': '%(asctime)s %(levelname)s %(name)s - %(message)s'
`), have a unique name per process and then filter the log afterwards... or you directly crate a new (temp) log file in each thread and merge later...

Answer (score 0):

Since you execute functions concurrently, it is expected **and important** that such logs are interleaved. This makes clear and explicit that those functions are not run sequentially and could help you during debugging.

You could improve logging by mentioning the file name in every log message relative to this file:

```
INFO : Starting application
INFO : Run pipeline on the available data
INFO : Generate preprocessed data for file data/toto.csv
INFO : Loading file data/toto.csv
INFO : Handle missing values of file data/toto.csv
INFO : Running pipeline on preprocessed data for file data/toto.csv
INFO : Success for file data/toto.csv
```

You can then filter and sort the logs by file name to improve readability.

Alternatively, you could remove the logging inside `Pipeline.run()` and return the logs are strings so that it is the caller responsibility to log the messages instead.

For instance:

```py
def foo(bar):
   log_msgs = [f"Foo started for {bar}"]
   result = do_things(bar)
   log_msgs.append(f"Foo ended for {bar}")

   return result, log_msgs
```

Then you collect all results and logs:

```py
import logging
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor

if __name__ == "__main__":
  bars = [...]

  with ThreadPoolExecutor() as pool:
    results = pool.map(foo, bars)
  
    # Log the messages in order
    for result, logs in results:
      for log in logs:
        logging.log(log)
```

Not that in this solution the log messages are created with f-strings for simplicity but it is not a recommended approach for logging as it decreases the performance.